# Complexity of finding the shortest simple even s-t-path

Tags: complexity-theory, graphs, shortest-path

Consider a graph $G=(V,E)$ and two vertices $s,t$.

> What is the complexity of finding the length of the shortest **simple** $s-t$ path that has even length?
>
> Does the problem become harder if the graph is edge weighted?

---

Note that the requirement that the path is simple makes it harder than to simply to use two copies of the graph

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? We do not want to just hand you the solution; we want you to gain understanding. However, as it is we do not know what your underlying problem is, so we can not begin to help. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/1284/98) for tips on asking questions about exercise problems. If you are uncertain how to improve your question, why not ask around in [chat]?

Comment: @Raphael - What makes you think that this is an exercise problem?

Comment: Because most people give more context and own thoughts if they encountered the problem on their own. That said, I would have posted that comment either way; just ignore the one sentence, the rest applies. Actually, the advice linked in that sentence applies as well, at least partly.

Comment: @Raphael - do you think that telling the readers that I heard this question from a student of mine in algorithms class would help the site users? I don't see why the context is relevant here. I was curious about this problem and Gilad gave a perfectly satisfying answer (given it, I'd say this would make quite a mean exercise :) ). I simply wanted to know what is known about the problem..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its in P for undirected graphs and NP hard for directed once:
http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/net.3230140403/pdf

Comment: Please elaborate a little bit to make this answer more useful. What is the algorithmic idea for the undirected case, and what the idea of a reduction for the directed one?

Comment: Also, please cite the article properly by giving title, author, year *and* a link (using the DOI).